# how to turn text vertical in internet explorer?

Tags: css

i have a menu which i want to display vertically. This is the css im using:

```
#portmenu li
{ 
  margin-top: 45px; 
  margin-left: -25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);     
  -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-bottom:5px;   
  border-left: 1px solid white;             
}
```

But this doesn't work in Internet explorer? It is fine in chrome and firefox?

Comment: Which internet explorer? [If it's >=IE9, you can use `-ms-transform`](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, don't do it. It looks really bad (pixelated). Why not just do:

```
M
y

T
e
x
t
```

??

Comment: This isn't what he's asking for. The CSS `transform` property rotates the entire block, including text, so the text wouldn't be vertical, it would be rotated.

Comment: I know that's NOT what he's asking for. That's why I said "don't do it".

Comment: Even still, that's better-suited as a comment, not as an answer, since you're not really answering his original question.